# YouTube api - Parse Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth

I am trying to create a playlist for the authenticated user. However I am receiving error

> domain:"global"
>
> message: "Parse Error"
>
> reason: "parseError"

Token is authenticated user's token.

```
var createPlaylistUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&access_token=' + token;

$.ajax ({
   type: "POST",
   url: createPlaylistUrl,
   dataType: 'json',
   async: false,
   contentType: "application/json",
   data: {'snippet.title': "TEST"},
   success: function (success){
       console.log("SUCCESS");
       console.log(success);
   },
   error: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
   }
});
```

I believe it's because of `{'snippet.title': "TEST"},` but the docs say I need to post `snippet.title`. If I don't post it, it returns I need to specify the Playlist Title name. Am I posting it in a wrong format? [Here is the docs.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert)

What am I doing wrong? How can I overcome this issue? :/

---

Update:

I also tried this and some other combinations. But couldn't find the right way. :(

```
   data: {
      snippet: {
         title: "TEST
      }
    }
```

and also:

```
    data: {
      'snippet': {
         'title': "TEST"
      }
    }
```

P.S: I am trying to build Chrome extension thus I couldn't get gapi client working. So I decided going with HTTP calls

**ANSWER = JSON.stringify(data)**

Comment: why don't you check the javascript example snippet given there and use that. Check here:- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert#examples (select javascript tab)

Comment: Because I am trying to use it for Chrome extension and apparently, I can't use the client library. I took a look at it and tried posting it in different formats, I keep getting the same error. `var data = { snippet { title: 'TEST' } }` or with wrapping it into `resources`?. What is the proper way?

Comment: There is error in your second attempt. Need to be `{
  "snippet": {
    "title": "test"
  }
}`

Comment: I tried them as strings too. Still same error

Comment: `success: function (response){
       console.log("SUCCESS");
       console.log(response);
   },
   error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
   }`  and still your second attempt have one missing quote.  please check.

Comment: There was a typo in the second attempt on the question. sorry. But it's still not working. It's never getting into success unfortunately. :/ I couldn't figure out how this object should look like.